# Gaussian distribution in python without using libraries

Tags: python, plotting, gaussian

I am implementing Gaussian distribution of a variable, but it gives multiple bell shapes. It should be a single bell shape. Below is my code and plot.

```
def gaussian_transform(arr):

    u=arr.mean()

    sig=arr.std()

    fd=[]

    a=0
    pi=math.pi
    for i in arr:

        a=((i-u)**2)/(2*(sig**2))
        e=math.exp(-a)
        fd.append((1/(sig*math.sqrt(2*pi))) * e)


    return fd


y=gaussian_transform(df.Age)

plt.plot(df.Age,y)

plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

`[image]

Comment: You are plotting a line that connects all points. if you want a might want to use [`plt.scatter()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort arr. For example you sort df.Age then apply the function and after plotting you will get a beautiful chart.

For example, I used your function and a range from 0 to 99 that is already sorted:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

arr = np.arange(100)
y=gaussian_transform(arr)
plt.plot(arr,y)
```

and got the following plot:

[image: pdf]

To make the plot smooth you need to add more points to the chart. In the following code I used vector functions of numpy to make the computation faster and write less code. I also used the linspace function to fill in the space between max and min of the data with more points for smooth charts.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def gaussian_plot(arr , n=1000):
    u = arr.mean()
    sig = arr.std()
    x = np.linspace(arr.min(), arr.max(), n)
    e = np.exp(-a)
    y = 1/(sig*math.sqrt(2*math.pi)) * e
    return x, y

arr = np.arange(100)
x, y=gaussian_plot(arr, 10000)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

And the result:
[image: pdf2]

Comment: thanks it works.but its not smooth curve.

Comment: I changed the answer to make a smooth curve

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer please mark it as answered.